# Qual o problema de relacionamento nestas tabelas?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou usando o `Laravel` e gostaria de fazer um relacionamento da **tabela** de `municipios` que contém o `estado_id`. O `estado_id` será relacionado com o `estado_id` da **tabela** de `estados`.

Logo ao executar a `query` me retornou o seguinte erro:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `banco_rep`.`#sql-26f8_16b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constr
>         aint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `municipios` add constraint `municipios_estados_id_foreign` foreign
>         key (`estados_id`) references `estados` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> [PDOException]
>         SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `banco_rep`.`#sql-26f8_16b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constr
>         aint is incorrectly formed")

Logo tenho os códigos `PHP`, parte na qual executo e crio o banco:

```
<?php    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;    
class CreateTableMunicipiosTable extends Migration
{
  /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('municipios');
    Schema::create('municipios', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('municipios_id');
      $table->integer('estados_id')->unsigned();
      $table->string('nome', 100);
      $table->char('cep',10);
      $table->foreign('estados_id')
      ->references('estados_id')
      ->on('estados')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
    });
  }    
  /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('municipios');
  }
}
```

***Crio o banco da tabela estados:***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;    
class CreateTableEstadosTable extends Migration
{
  /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('estados');
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('estados_id');
      $table->string('nome', 100);
      $table->char('sigla', 2);
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
    });
  }    
  /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function down()
  {

    Schema::dropIfExists('estados');
  }
}
```

***Model Estados:***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estados extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['estados_id','nome','sigla'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function municipios()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Municipios');
  }
}
```

***Model Municipios:***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Municipios extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['municipios_id','estados_id', 'nome', 'cep'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  public function estados()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Estados');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Everson. Como assim tirar as aspas? As aspas não são obrigatórias?

Comment: O seus dois `models` estão errados, porque as chaves não podem estar na configuração `$fillable` e sim na configuração `$primaryKey` porque você mudou o padrão, mas, o problema do erro é porque a tabela já existe, não é melhor você zerar o migration e rodar novamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça as seguintes alterações:

**No Model Municípios**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Municipios extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['municipios_id','estados_id', 'nome', 'cep'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  public function estados()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Estados','estados_id','estados_id');
  }
}
```

**No Model Estado**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estados extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['estados_id','nome','sigla'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function municipios()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Municipios','estados_id','estados_id');
  }
}
```